# Unused local variable false positive

Tags: java, sonarqube, unused-variables

While using sonar lint version 6.3.0.39716, it reports the following variable as unused.

```
void read() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s; // unused local variable 's'
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        }
}
```

But the variable `s` is used in the next line, should this be considered as unused as `s` is just assigned a value? 
Edit-
This is not considered an unused local variable.

```
void read() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s; // ok
        s = reader.readLine();
        while (s != null) {
            s = reader.readLine();
        }
}
```

Here also s is just assigned value apart from being used in a boolean condition which it is used in the above case also.

Comment: `s = reader.readLine()` is assigning `s`, but after it is assigned it isn't used anywhere, because the while loop does nothing with that assigned value. You could just as well delete the variable and just do `while (reader.readLine() != null)` and the code would work exactly the same. That's why it is considered unused.

Comment: Isn't it used while checking `!= null`

Comment: `while (reader.readLine() != null){}` achieves the same result but without an unused local variable

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I edited it to make my doubt more clear

Comment: Still, the point of sonarqube is to detect that this variable is useless, the code can be reduced to my comment without any other adverse effects. `s` is never to used to assign it to anyhting else. The second snippet is too complex for sonarqube to understand. This is not a false positive but a very good normal positive and you should change your code to my comment or actually use `s` or drop the method entirely. Depends on what you actually want the method to do.

Comment: `(s = reader.readLine()) != null`  is not using/reading the variable `s`, it is the result of the assignment expression that is compared to `null` (I wonder how you do consider you first example as a false positive (obviously there is no use for `s`; which is not the case for all other examples (including following comment))

Comment: So other examples where a boolean is just used as a flag and never updated are not FP's. eg- `boolean a = true; if(a) {}` here a is not considered as unused.

Comment: but `if ((a = true) == true) {}` makes `a` unused.

Comment: @user16320675 How it is not reading the variable `s`?

Comment: @user16320675 I am a bit confused can you explain in a more detailed way what you are trying to tell.

Comment: first explain how `(s = reader.readLine())`  is reading the value of `s` ? or better, using its stored value (not the value being stored into it that is, being assigned? (from a logical/processing view, obviously at the end it is the same value)

Comment: it is not reading, this is just assignment, isn't it reading when compared to null, I mean to ask isn't `if((s = reader.readLine()) != null)` same as `s = reader.readLine(); if(s != null)`

Comment: Oh man. You are not comparing `s` to `null`! You are comparing the value of the expression `(s = reader.readLine())` to `null`!

Comment: Though I agree that (a) `s` counts as unused, and (b) there is no reason at all for the generated code to fetch the value of `s` after assigning it, it is nevertheless true that the result of the assignment is the value of the variable `s`.   From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26): *At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred*.  But pragmatically, I suggest taking the sonarcube recommendation as meaning "there is no point to having this variable, so remove it".

Comment: Logical point yes it is unused but at runtime, the variable is used, in the end, I think logical reasoning will stand out.

Comment: It is not 'used'. See the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) for the distinction between 'assigned/initialized' and 'used'.  *A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).*  The quoted sentence would be vacuous if assigning a value counted as 'using' the variable.

Comment: @user16632363 After reading the JLS links you mentioned I have come to some decisions. The variable `s` is used as it has been assigned a value during runtime and while comparing it to null i.e. `(s = reader.readLine()) != null` the assignment happens first and then the value is read as at run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred. The result of an assignment expression is not itself a variable. So it will access the value of variable only to check, correct if I am wrong. Though `s` isn't of any use, it is used in boolean.

Comment: NO. The variable is not used, the assignment returns the value assigned, but not the value of s, but the value that is assigned during assignment, it is the same value but it is not read from s. And therefore s is only ever assigned, never read, never compared, never used.

Comment: @luk2302 How are you saying that assignment returns the value assigned when it is mentioned that The result of an assignment expression is not itself a variable.

Comment: Because when you write (for example) `x = y + z`, the generated code has the sum of `y` and `z` somewhere, probably a register.  The sum does not somehow vanish when a copy of the value is stored into `x`; and therefore that sum is available to further computations without have to be "read" from `x`.

Comment: @user16632363 I really appreciate your time and effort but is this for sure true, I mean can you point out some documentation regarding it, actually I am unit testing and I need to be sure to add such a case.

Comment: In my opinion, [the link I posted before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) covers it.

Answer (score 1):

For this code

```
void read() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s; // unused local variable 's'
    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    }
}
```

The variable `s` can be removed completely without side effects as shown below.

```
void read() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while ((reader.readLine()) != null) {
    }
}
```

This is why these code analyzers will point out that the variable in question is never used. Setting a value in a variable is not enough to deem a variable as "used". In the second snippet, the variable `s` can't be removed because it is used to make a decision:

```
    while (s != null) {...}
```

Because of the line above, removing the variable will result in a compilation error. Therefore, the variable is an important part of the code.